# Multi-Select enum for every day in calendar

Tags: checkboxes, multi-selection, calendar

I'm currently trying to solve an organization problem inside of my calendar.

**My requirements:**

I have a list of possibilities.

1. You can add these possibilities to every day of the month.
2. It should also be allowed two have two possibilities on the same day, but not the same one more than once.
3. Each possibility can be used multiple times.

e.g. 2nd of June, Washing, Cooking. 3nd of June Washing, 4th of June Cooking, 5th of June nothing, 6th of June Washing, Cooking, Watching TV

Regarding these requirements, how should I implement it?

Currently I got the following implementation:
[image]

If you press on a day it switches through the possibilities. This doesn't cover my requirement to allow more than one per day.

I thought about having a "multi"-checkbox for every day but this is not very good ui to look at. Also I don't have enough space to make it clearly visible inside of every day.

As this view is already a popup I tried to avoid opening a second popup when clicking on a day. But I guess this would be the cleanest solution?

The customers do want have a clear overview over every day so I can't get rid of a calendar-view.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards

Comment: How many possibilities are there? How many items will a typical day have (a rough estimation is fine)? Is there a maximum amount of items per day?

Comment: 5 possibilities, up to 5 per day and only in a few cases more than one or two possibilities

Answer (score 1):

1.. Without additional popup:

To add a possibility: You could make a possibility a drag and drop and validate on drop whether you already have a possibility added to that day. You would have to make sure that even after drag, your original/source possibility list does not change.

To delete a possibility: Add a small delete image button against each possibility in each day.

To display the possibilities: Perhaps a little scroll bar to the day with multiple possibilities. Although, it might not look very nice.

2.. With additional popup: On click of the day

It could be a little form where a checkbox list could be used to display possibilities and add/remove possibility.

To avoid opening another popup, you could hide the calendar popup on click of a particular day and diaplay it again on close of the day view.

Answer (score 1):

The following can be an option to present this scenario:

Clicking a cell in calendar, a menu displays the available options. You can select the required options and click anywhere to close the menu. The cell displays the number of selections.

[image]